# EXCEL Bar Graph - representing only part of the bar graph

Tags: excel, graph, highlight, partial

Hi I'm trying to create a bar graph on Excel where I can highlight part of the bar graph. For instance, for the following table,

1  100  20  30

2  100  10  20

3  100  5   15

I would like to have the value 100 represented and then on top of that have only between 20 and 30 highlighted (or shaded/colored/etc in differnt color) - showing that the total is 100 and the range is 20 to 30.

For 2, same thing, have 100 represented first, and only have 10 to 20 highlighted, and so on.

Would any of you guys please help me on how to go about it? I tried stacked bar with no fill and such but it does not fulfill my satisfaction. Thank you for your reply in advance!!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

[image: Chart]

If so, convert your data to this format:

```
1   20  10  70
2   10  10  80
3   5   10  85
```

Use a stacked column chart and set the first and the third series to the same color.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Yes, this is exactly what I want to do, and I have converted my data to the format that you presented; However, how do I set the first and third series to the same color? And by first and third you mean the series with (20,10,5) and (70,80,85) right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean by first and third series. I don't have Excel right now (I used Google Drive for the screenshot) but try right-clicking on one of the columns for the third series and choosing Customize or something like that. There should be an option to select the color.

Comment: This might help as well: http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/change-fills-and-lines-in-charts-HP005198803.aspx